# AngularJS how to pass data from one controller to different directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am not sure whether I can do like this or there is a better way. I need someone to guide me.

I created two template using directive (both directives in the same page).
Let say

- directiveVideo for display videos
- directivePhoto for display photos

Then I have a controller. this controller requests two different data, videos and photos.
My question is, how can I pass the video data to display in directiveVideo and photo data to
directivePhoto

Answer (score 2):

Your question is incredibly vague, so I'll give an equally vague answer. If you want something more specific, you'll need to edit your question to include some code - preferably in a Plunker.

If your controller declares two scope vars, `videos` and `photos`, then you can simply pass those as attributes to your directives:

```html
<div photos="photos"></div>
<div videos="videos"></div>
```

And you can read this in from your directive. Assuming you have an isolate scope:

```js
scope: { photos: '=' }
```

Otherwise:

```js
scope: true,
link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
  attrs.$observe( 'photos', function ( val ) {
    $scope.photos = val;
  });
}
```

And your template can access it however it needs to:

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos"><img ng-src="{{photo.url}}" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for my question because I haven't try it out myself so I quite blur about it. I will requestion or update it again after i try.